# Check if string is numeric

Tags: c

Can you please check what is wrong with this function? This function checks whether a string is numeric or not. If it is numeric (positive and negative integers and decimals are allowed), it returns a value of 1. Else, it returns 0. I tried to run the code and the output always returns 0.

```
{int is_valid (char strval[])
{
int strlen, ascii_code, i;
int decimal=-1, negative=-1;

strlen=strlen_safe(strval);

for (i=0; i<strlen; i++)
{
    ascii_code=(int)strval[i];

    if(ascii_code==44)
        return 0;
    else if(ascii_code==45)
    {
        negative++;
        if(negative||i!=0)
            return 0;
    }
    else if(ascii_code==46)
    {
        decimal++;
        if(decimal>0)
            return 0;
    }
    else if(ascii_code<48||ascii_code>57)
        return 0;
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: unsigned int that is negative?

Comment: Why the specific check for 44?

Comment: do not use numbers like `45`, use `'-'` much more readable. And look into stdlib `strtol` or `strtof`.

Comment: Have you try running step by step your code using a debugger ?

Comment: @alex edited it. hehe thank you. but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @unwind to check if a comma occurs. Example (1,000: it should be invalid)

Comment: @pusa Yes, but that's covered by the final `else`.

Comment: @ThomasChristensen If the intent is to really check for *ASCII*, you can't use `'-'` unless you know that the target character set is ASCII. This looks wrong, but might be right.

Comment: @ThomasChristensen i don't know how to use strtol and strof in this function. I have troubles understanding string functions.

Comment: @pusa Use them instead of this function. They can validate for you.

Comment: @unwind True. Now since he writes ASCII in his code I assume that it is ASCII. BTW it would work for UTF-8 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine with checking that a string is a number on the current platform (which might not be using ASCII as its encoding), you should just use `strtod()`. It will handle all the subtle ways a floating-point number can be formatted, and generally be much nicer to your users:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_valid_number(const char *s, size_t maxdigits)
{
  char *endp;

  strtod(s, &endp);
  const size_t digits = (size_t) (endp - s);
  return *endp == '\0' && digits <= maxdigits;
}
```

The above is very conservative, it requires that all characters of the incoming string be part of the number. This means `"43 "` (note trailing space) would be rejected.

To make it accept just a prefix, change the final line to

```
return endp != s;
```

Comment: this is somewhat useful but whenever I input -1234msds it is considered valid :o

Comment: @pusa it really shouldn't, and I just tested it, it works for me. :) `"-1234msds"` is rejected.

Comment: Hi! I would like to limit the strlen to 9. But when I try to do the code considering the strlen, it didn't work. Can you help me how can I revise the code?

Comment: @pusa I've tried, not tested but something like that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert `strval[i]` to `int`.

If `'-'` appears not in the beginning of the string, it will still reguard the string as a number.

If `strlen_safe` is your own function, it may be where the code fails.

This code  should work.

```
int is_valid (char strval[])
{
    if(!*strval)
        return 0;
    if(*strval=='-')
        strval++;
    char decimal=0;
    while(*strval)
    {
        if(!isdigit(*strval))
        {
            if(*strval=='.')
            {
                if(decimal)
                    return 0;
                decimal=1;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
        strval++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @v78dpo4 the function always returns 0 :<

Comment: @pusa I tried it. It worked. How are you getting your string? Maybe there is a problem with the way you are getting the string.